# for loop in Perl (how to do something with each url)

Tags: perl

Look at @arr and @arre, cose of that I geting  error on:
line 20: 
Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 20.

line 20`for our $post (@{ $resp->{data} }) {`

```
sub graph_api {

  unlink "data.txt";
  open(MYFILE2, ">data.txt");
  close(MYFILE2);

  our @arr = (
    "me/inbox?fields=comments.limit(2)&limit=1",
    "me/home?fields=name,link,from,story,is_hidden,message&limit=1"
  );

  foreach our $arre (@arr) {
    my $uri = new URI("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $arre . "&access_token=");

    chomp(my $content = get $uri);
    die "Couldn't get $uri" unless defined $content;

    our $resp = get("$uri");

    defined $resp ? decode_json($resp) : undef;
  }
```

But when I change this pert all works fine:

```
our @arr = ("me/inbox?fields=comments.limit(2)&limit=1","me/home?fields=name,link,from,story,is_hidden,message&limit=1");

  my $uri = new URI("https://graph.facebook.com/".$arr[0]."&access_token=");
```

Comment: What didn't work?  What were you trying to do?

Comment: Add `use strict; use warnings;` and fix the issues it identifies.  There are at least two barewords in the code shown; you need double quotes around your argument to `get`: `get("www.$arr[$i].com");`.

Comment: By the way, if you don't need the index $i for anything other than indexing into @arr, you should use `foreach my $domain (@arr) { my $url = "www.$domain.com"; (etc)}`

Comment: Its ok with "", I puted it in main code... When I tryed without for like this ("www.$arr[0].com") it works... I tryed with foreach too...

Comment: Please preserve the original question to preserve the integrity of the answers.  Add to the question.

Comment: 0_0 Reopen votes? Seriously? Why?!

Answer (score 6):

#### Initial question

The original version of the question asked about the code fragment:

```
my @arr(somting somting1); 
for my $i(0 .. $#arr){ 
    my url = get (www.$arr[$i].com); 
    do something with url... 
}
```

The question has since been updated, losing this information.

#### Initial response

Add:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

and fix the issues it identifies.  Experts use them to make sure they don't make silly mistakes.  Beginners need to use them for the same reason.

There are at least four barewords in the code shown.

The syntax for initializing `@arr` is wrong.  Use one of these:

```
my @arr = ( "somting", "somting1" );
my @arr = qw( somting somting1 );
```

You need double quotes around your argument to `get`:

```
get("www.$arr[$i].com");
```

And more idiomatic Perl would use:

```
for my $core (@arr)
{
    my $url = get("www.$core.com");
    ...check...use...
}
```

---

#### Response to revised question

You are getting an error:

```
Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 20.
```

on line 20 which is, apparently:

```
for our $post (@{ $resp->{data} }) {
```

The notation `$resp->{data}` is trying to treat `$resp` as a hash reference, but `$resp` is not a hash reference.  Your code contains:

```
defined $resp ? decode_json($resp) : undef;
```

It suggests that `$resp` might be undefined in the `for` loop, or that it contains a string (maybe some JSON) that needs to be decoded.  Did you perhaps mean:

```
$resp = (defined $resp) ? decode_json($resp) : undef;
```

I'm intrigued that you're using `our` variables instead of `my` variables.  It isn't precisely wrong, but it is unusual.  Use `my` unless you have an explicit reason to use `local` or `our` instead.

Comment: I get this error Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 20.

Comment: @Hellena - Which line is line 20? That error message is useless to us without more context!

Comment: I can't see what's on line 20 of your script.  At a guess, it means your `get` method isn't expecting a string but a hash, in which case you need to look at the manual page for `get` (or whatever other code is on line 20).  If the module you're using isn't a fairly standard one, we aren't going to be able to help.

Comment: @Hellena - Okay, so you're trying to use a scalar--namely `$resp`--as a hash reference. Don't do that.

Comment: But all works fine if I don't use for loop...

Comment: @Hellena - Whatever you've assigned to `$resp` (ie the output of `get()`) is not a hash reference. Don't try to use something that isn't a hash reference as though it is a hash reference. It would be helpful if you could describe what you're trying to do.

Comment: I trying to get messages and new posts from facebook... There is no problem when I want get only post or only messages... But when I try to get it together getting error message...$arr[0] is post $arr[1] is message...

Comment: @Hellena - Why are you calling `get($uri)` twice within each loop?

Comment: this is plumb:chomp(my $content = get $uri);
    die "Couldn't get $uri" unless defined $content;

Comment: @Hellena - "this is plumb"? I have absolutely no idea what you think you mean by that. Take some time to **think** and formulate your responses.

Comment: maybe there is problem cose it get content form 2 urls na puting it in $resp?

Comment: @JackManey: thank you for continuing to try to help Hellena. I suspect English is not Hellena's native language (and we'd probably both be struggling to write in her native language). Hellena, please note that (a) it's best to preserve the integrity of the question (and answers) when editing, and (b) it's likely that you need to add more information to your question. As Jack suggests, you should take enough time to create a good edit. It is going to be hard for someone (like me) without a Facebook account to run your code. It may be sensible to write a new question, taking time to do it well.

Comment: I don't know how to say it on english.. I thought this is trash: chomp(my $content = get $uri); die "Couldn't get $uri" unless defined $content

Comment: @Hellena - What "two urls"? You're calling the same function (namely `get`) on each URL twice within each iteration of the loop, and assigning (presumably) the same result to two different variables (one of which is `chomp`ed and the other of which is not).

Comment: @Hellena - If it's trash, then why did you include it in the question? Please give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The `chomp(my $content = get $uri); die "Couldn't get $uri" unless defined $content;` is curious.  I would test before chomping: `my $content = get $uri; die "Couldn't get $uri" unless defined $content;` and only then would I consider `chomp $content`.  This assumes the content is returned as a string.

Comment: but thats part is unnecessary.. It can be removed...

Comment: @Hellena - If it can be removed, then why did you include it in the first place? I'd recommend going through your code line by line and making sure that a) you've removed any unnecessary code and b) that you understand what each line does.

Comment: Look at main post... If I change that part I added it works fine...

Comment: @Hellena - Define "works fine". I still don't really know what you're trying to do. Also, you don't seem to do anything with `$resp` in each iteration, except this: `defined $resp ? decode_json($resp) : undef;`. However, you neither assign the return value of this ternary operator, but you don't store the value of `decode_json($resp)` when `$resp` is defined. Unless `json_decode` changes its argument in place...

Comment: works fine mean if I use ONLY FIRST element from array or ONLY SECOND element... But If I try use them together with for loop it couses error

Comment: @Hellena - Again: why are you defining `$resp` in each iteration of the loop and then not doing anything with it to make it last beyond the scope of the iteration in which it was defined?

Comment: In supplement I added in main post you can see when it work fine, I used only first element from array '$arr[0]'

Comment: In $resp I getting content and than decode it...

Comment: @Hellena - That doesn't answer the question: why are you trying to use `$resp` when it's only defined within the loop? Where are you storing the decoded content?

Comment: here: our $post (@{ $resp->{data} }) {
and then dump it...

Comment: @Hellena - But that is **outside** of the loop.

Comment: @JackManey: how does the fact that it's a module (`our`) variable alter things?  Is it accessible outside the loop because of that?

Comment: yes... It must be inside loop?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I thought that, too, for a moment, but a quick check shows that variables declared with `our` within a loop still don't survive outside of a loop. `perl -e 'use strict;use warnings;foreach (1..10){our $blah = $_;}print "$blah\n";'` produces "Variable "$blah" is not imported at -e line 1.
Global symbol "$blah" requires explicit package name at -e line 1."

Comment: You've still not shown us exactly the code you're executing.  The line numbers don't tie up, and you must have at least a `use URI;`.  Have you got `use strict; use warnings;` at the top too?  If so, is the code compiling without any warnings?  If not, why aren't you fixing the warnings.  The second `for` loop that you're saying produces the error isn't shown in its context.  All this makes it hard to help you!

Comment: I think only problem is cose it store two elements from array into $resp?

Comment: @Hellena - The problem is that **outside of your loop, `$resp` does not exist.**

Comment: ...Or, if it does exist, it is a different variable that was not affected by the loop.  And you can only store one response at a time in a scalar variable like `$resp`.  If you need an array of responses, use an array instead of a scalar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - True, it's impossible to tell whether or not Hellena has defined `$resp` elsewhere.

Comment: I have to go to work; I'm probably not going to respond to this any more.  Please look up the SSCCE guidelines (several comments have links to the web site that explains what that is).  And I suggest a carefully crafted new question demonstrating that you've learned from this question and its answers.

Comment: Likewise. I think I'm done here.

Comment: thanks guys... I will try few more things if I solve I will put here.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use index variables like that to loop over your array.  Iterate over the array directly like this:

```
my @domains = ( ... );
for my $domain ( @domains ) {
    my $url = "http://www.$host.com";
    ...
}
```

And, as others have said, always `use strict; use warnings;`, especially as a beginner.

Comment: I get this error Can't use string ("") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 20.

Comment: Since we can't see line 20 of your script, we can't help.  Add (to then end of the question — you can edit your own question) enough of your script to make it compile and generate the error. See how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can help.